# Check for existence of string in a list of strings

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet that contains something like this:

```
[MATCH HISTORY]

A1
Playername

John
Paul
Joe
Mitch
Jimmy
```

and another spread sheet that looks like this:

```
[PLAYERS]

A1
Players

Martin
John
Paul
Joe
Michael
Elliot
```

As you can see `"JIMMY"` does not exist in the `"PLAYERS"` list on the `"PLAYERS"` spreadsheet - how do i flag this up on the `"MATCH HISTORY"` sheet - using conditional formatting or something to that effect and/or is there a way to automatically populate the players sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can create a *Conditional Formatting Rule* based upon a formula. Excel 2010 and later can use references to other worksheets in that formula. There are work-arounds using named ranges with workbook scope for earlier versions but this solution is targeted towards 2010 and above and will reference the other worksheet directly.

First select column A from the MATCH HISTORY worksheet (with A1 as the *active cell*) and choose Home ► Styles ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule. When the Create New Rule dialog opens, select *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and supply the following for *-Format values where this formula is true:*

`=AND(ROW($A1)>1, $A1<>"", ISNA(MATCH($A1, Players!$A:$A, 0)))`

Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and select some distinctive formatting. In the following sample image, I chose an orange *Fill*. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to accept the formatting then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule. You results should be similar to the following.

[image: No Matching Players]

It seems that both *Jimmy* and *Mitch* are missing from the PLAYERS worksheet. Auto-populating hte PLAYERS worksheet would require VBA or a calculation intensive 'list unique' *array formula* filled into enough rows to allow headroom for future additions.